# Vim oddities in keymapping

Tags: vim, keymapping

I like to insert blank lines without entering insert mode and I used this keymapping:

```
nomap go o <esc>
```

This does create the blank line but introduces some weird behaviour. I have smart indent and autoindent set. The new line follows the indents but doesn't remove them even though doing so manually automatically removes the redundant whitespace. It also adds a single whitespace where the cursor is each time.

Anyone have any insights as to explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim is *very* literal with how you write your mapping commands - it's actually processing the space in your mapping before it does the **`<ESC>`**. In other words, your mapping does this:

```
nnoremap go o<SPACE><ESC>
```

You should change it to:

```
nnoremap go o<ESC>
```

And make sure you don't have any extra spaces in the mapping!

Comment: D'oh! I was looking at the wrong problem! I assumed that it was just a list of key mappings rather than literal user input. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "too much php".
This is the relevant section from my .vimrc

```
nnoremap <A-o> o<ESC>k
nnoremap <A-O> O<ESC>j
```

I think it's faster since you get the cursor back at the original line (Although not on the original character).

Comment: Try this then: 'nnoremap <A-o> mto<ESC>`t'

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) has a useful tip: [Quickly adding and deleting empty lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quickly_adding_and_deleting_empty_lines). The trick is to `set paste` before adding the new line and afterwards `set nopaste`. Additionally, this will set a mark to remember the cursor position and jump back to where you were.

```
nnoremap go :set paste<CR>m`o<Esc>``:set nopaste<CR>
nnoremap gO :set paste<CR>m`O<Esc>``:set nopaste<CR>
```